# Excel count number of continuous occurrences of values and replaces with specific calculation

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have excel data with more that 100,000 rows. I have only a single column which contains values in a column with either 0 or greater than 0.

When values are 0, I want to count continuous occurrences of 0s in that column until higher value is reached. Lets say I started traversing and found sample value of 24, then I stop there and count totals of 0s until now.  Lets say total zeros 24 until were 4. I will divided 1 by 4 and replace all 0s with 0.25. If total is 10, then 1 has to be divided by 10 then 0.1 will replace all zeros until found.

Then same process to continue down after higher values is 0 again. Then I count 0s again and do same calculation as above.

The data before:

[image]

And here is sample of what is require:

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Power Query, available in Window Excel 2010+ and Office 365

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***

```
let

//Change table name in next line to your actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],

//set the data type
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"duration_in_days", Int64.Type}}),

//group by each group of 0's plus the non-zero entry
    //add an index column
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),

    //add a custom column that copies over a number from Index only if the data is non-zero
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "grps", each if [duration_in_days]=0 then null else [Index]),

    //fill up to create a group for each sequence
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Added Custom",{"grps"}),

//Group by the grouping sequence
    group = Table.Group(#"Filled Up","grps",{

        //generate a LIST according to you divide/by rules, adding the last entry at the end
        {"duration_in_days", each 
            let 
                cnt = Table.RowCount(_),
                newList = if List.RemoveItems([duration_in_days],{0}) = {}
                    then {} //List.Repeat({null}, cnt)
                    else  List.Repeat({1/(cnt-1)},cnt-1) & {List.Last([duration_in_days])}
                in newList, type list}
        }),

//remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(group,{"grps"}),

//expand the list
    #"Expanded duration_in_days" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "duration_in_days"),

//The blank "rows" will just be the last row if there was no terminating non-zero number
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded duration_in_days", each 
        not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),

//set the data type
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Blank Rows",{{"duration_in_days", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

[image]

Comment: If you can't use Power Query and still want a VBA macro solution, then check out [**this explanation**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65250212/14094617) (a few simple changes to the code will give you a working solution).

Comment: +1 and super interesting approach. TIL `Table.FillUp`, `List.Repeat` and `List.Last`.

Comment: First of all , thank you for responding and providing the solution. When i deploy the code as instructed, I am getting error: Expression.Error: 5 arguments were passed to function which expects between 2 and 4.
Details:
    Pattern=
    Arguments=List

Comment: @Programmer I cannot reproduce your error by copy/pasting the code that I posted. Hard to tell what you did differently. Try copy/pasting the code again, making only the necessary name in the Table name.  Then select each applied step to see which line first shows the error

Comment: I have exact same data as I posted in my question. Only 1 column and that column has sample values as I posted above. I reproduced your solution as you instructed by only changing table name to my Table name which was 'Table3'.

Comment: @Programmer and which step shows the error?

Comment: @Programmer Alternatively, share an **xlsx** workbook that demonstrates the problem by uploading it to some public sharing site (eg OneDrive, DropBox, etc) and posting a link here. (Be sure to remove any confidential information first).

Comment: After posting the code in advance editor and changing the table name, when I click done, this error comes, Is there any way, I can post screenshot?

Comment: https://ibb.co/0V8ymf4 This is screenshot of the error

Comment: @Programmer Screenshot is not at all helpful.  Please follow one of my two suggestions in my comments to allow me to troubleshoot the error.  I suspect examining your workbook will be the most useful of the two, though.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Here is the link to the excel file shared online. I am using Office 2016  Desktop. https://1drv.ms/x/s!AscucLrolgCR_UbBBr54Q_osJgfx?e=0nNOhe

Comment: @Programmer Could not reproduce your error with your file. I - downloaded your file.  - Converted the Data into a **Table**. - Opened the Query. - Obtained the desired result.

Comment: I have tried once again, but still same issue. I think I am doing mistake in first two lines. When I am going into advance editor, I take note of Table Name and then delete what ever I see. Then I am pasting your code and replacing table name with the name of table that PQ generated. Still error remains. Am i doing any mistake?

Comment: @Programmer I don't know.  But the workbook you uploaded does NOT show the error.  The error in that table is due to the data not being in a **Table**.  Which Applied Step is first showing your too many arguments error?

Comment: Did some research on internet, and got a clue that it might be a PowerQuery version issue. The PQ in Office 2016 might have old function version that's why it is showing wrong number of arguments error. For experiment, I did try it on latest version of Office, the Office 2021. It works perfect. Turned out issue was Office 2016 and PowerQuery version. BTW Thank you for your kind follow up comments. @RonRosenfeld